# How to check if the value of the last key of a JSON ends with a comma using RegEx?

Tags: python, json, regex, python-3.x

I have the following JSON:

```js
{
  "markers": [
    {
      "name": "Rixos The Palm Dubai",
      "position": [25.1212, 55.1535],
    },
    {
      "name": "Shangri-La Hotel",
      "description": "some description",
    },
    {
      "value": 123445,
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to create a RegEx that can find all cases where the value of the last key or array ends with a `,` and remove it using Python and the `re` library. In the JSON above, all values should have their commas removed.

I've already tried using `\,[^.]+\}` So it can find arrays or objects ending with a value with a `,` but the RegEx doesn't stop after finding another `,` or `{`for instance. [Here's what I mean](https://regex101.com/r/xnBTCg/1).

Now, I know I shouldn't be using RegEx to handle a JSON, but this is a very specific case and it won't cause any trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a positive lookahead pattern instead to match only a `,` that is followed by either a `}` or a `]` with optional white spaces in between:

```
,(?=\s*[}\]])
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/xnBTCg/3

Answer (score 1):

`(?=^[^:\n]*:[^:\n]*$).*(,)(?=\s*[\}\]])$`

This regex uses a positive lookahead to assert that on one line, there's a `:` somewhere, which indicates the presence of a key-value pair for your data. The non-lookahead portion matches one comma at the end of a line. The final lookahead asserts that the next line contains only whitespace and a closing bracket or curly brace.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZXPMaF/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
\,(\s*)(?=\}|])
```

[image]

Replace by `\1`

[`Regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/xnBTCg/4)